# Git: Erasing the history of a file?

Tags: git, github

I have been pushing to a repo for a while. At one moment we had a Base.pm perl module where we kept also some passwords. Later we removed the passwords, but since git (& github.com) remembers everything, when I check the "history" of the Base.pm file I can see old versions where the passwords still appeared.

I want to erase the history of that file. Is there an easy way to make this?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Answer (score 3):

Even if you erase the file, the passwords have still been visible to the public. They may even *continue* to be visible via things like [The Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php). So no matter what, you need to change your passwords. Once you do that, it doesn't matter so much whether the file stays in git or not.

Comment: Actually, this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: @DamjanPavlica Would you like to explain, or are we supposed to just take your word for it?